# Как вставить картинку в RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вставляются вместо картинки символы

яШяаЃЉИ...

```
    ImageOpenDialog1();



    public void ImageOpenDialog1()
    {
        // Configure open file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents |*.jpg"; // Filter files by extension

        // Show open file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Open document
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            //
            textEditor.Load(dlg.FileName);

        }
    }
```

Обновлено:

```
public class TextEditor : RichTextBox /*Control*/, ITextEditorComponent, IServiceProvider, IWeakEventListener 
    {
        #region Constructors
        static TextEditor()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextEditor),
                                                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextEditor)));
            FocusableProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextEditor),
                                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Boxes.True));
        }
...
        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the text from the stream, auto-detecting the encoding.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This method sets <see cref="IsModified"/> to false.
        /// </remarks>
        public void Load(Stream stream)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = FileReader.OpenStream(stream, this.Encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8)) {
                this.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                SetCurrentValue(EncodingProperty, reader.CurrentEncoding); // assign encoding after ReadToEnd() so that the StreamReader can autodetect the encoding
            }
            SetCurrentValue(IsModifiedProperty, Boxes.False);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the text from the stream, auto-detecting the encoding.
        /// </summary>
        public void Load(string fileName)
        {
            if (fileName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
                Load(fs);
            }
        }
```

Добавлено

```
public class TextEditor : RichTextBox /*Control*/, ITextEditorComponent, IServiceProvider, IWeakEventListener 
    {

....
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/Sets the document displayed by the text editor.
        /// This is a dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public TextDocument Document {
            get { return (TextDocument)GetValue(DocumentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DocumentProperty, value); }
        }
```

TextDocument

```
namespace ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is the main class of the text model. Basically, it is a <see cref="System.Text.StringBuilder"/> with events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <b>Thread safety:</b>
    /// <inheritdoc cref="VerifyAccess"/>
    /// <para>However, there is a single method that is thread-safe: <see cref="CreateSnapshot()"/> (and its overloads).</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public sealed class TextDocument : IDocument, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    ...

    #region Fields + Constructor
    readonly Rope<char> rope;
    readonly DocumentLineTree lineTree;
    readonly LineManager lineManager;
    readonly TextAnchorTree anchorTree;
    readonly TextSourceVersionProvider versionProvider = new TextSourceVersionProvider();

    /// <summary>
    /// Create an empty text document.
    /// </summary>
    public TextDocument()
        : this(string.Empty)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new text document with the specified initial text.
    /// </summary>
    public TextDocument(IEnumerable<char> initialText)
    {
        if (initialText == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("initialText");
        rope = new Rope<char>(initialText);
        lineTree = new DocumentLineTree(this);
        lineManager = new LineManager(lineTree, this);
        lineTrackers.CollectionChanged += delegate {
            lineManager.UpdateListOfLineTrackers();
        };

        anchorTree = new TextAnchorTree(this);
        undoStack = new UndoStack();
        FireChangeEvents();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new text document with the specified initial text.
    /// </summary>
    public TextDocument(ITextSource initialText)
        : this(GetTextFromTextSource(initialText))
    {
    }

    // gets the text from a text source, directly retrieving the underlying rope where possible
    static IEnumerable<char> GetTextFromTextSource(ITextSource textSource)
    {
        if (textSource == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textSource");

        #if NREFACTORY
        if (textSource is ReadOnlyDocument)
            textSource = textSource.CreateSnapshot(); // retrieve underlying text source, which might be a RopeTextSource
        #endif

        RopeTextSource rts = textSource as RopeTextSource;
        if (rts != null)
            return rts.GetRope();

        TextDocument doc = textSource as TextDocument;
        if (doc != null)
            return doc.rope;

        return textSource.Text;
    }
    #endregion
```

IDocument

```
namespace ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document
{
    #if !NREFACTORY
    /// <summary>
    /// A document representing a source code file for refactoring.
    /// Line and column counting starts at 1.
    /// Offset counting starts at 0.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IDocument : ITextSource, IServiceProvider
    {
        #if NREFACTORY
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an immutable snapshot of this document.
        /// </summary>
        IDocument CreateDocumentSnapshot();
        #endif

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/Sets the text of the whole document..
        /// </summary>
        new string Text { get; set; } // hides ITextSource.Text to add the setter

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is called directly before a change is applied to the document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// It is invalid to modify the document within this event handler.
        /// Aborting the change (by throwing an exception) is likely to cause corruption of data structures
        /// that listen to the Changing and Changed events.
        /// </remarks>
        event EventHandler<TextChangeEventArgs> TextChanging;

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is called directly after a change is applied to the document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// It is invalid to modify the document within this event handler.
        /// Aborting the event handler (by throwing an exception) is likely to cause corruption of data structures
        /// that listen to the Changing and Changed events.
        /// </remarks>
        event EventHandler<TextChangeEventArgs> TextChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// This event is called after a group of changes is completed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="EndUndoableAction"/>
        event EventHandler ChangeCompleted;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of lines in the document.
        /// </summary>
        int LineCount { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the document line with the specified number.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lineNumber">The number of the line to retrieve. The first line has number 1.</param>
        IDocumentLine GetLineByNumber(int lineNumber);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the document line that contains the specified offset.
        /// </summary>
        IDocumentLine GetLineByOffset(int offset);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the offset from a text location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="GetLocation"/>
        int GetOffset(int line, int column);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the offset from a text location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="GetLocation"/>
        int GetOffset(TextLocation location);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the location from an offset.
        /// </summary>
        /// <seealso cref="GetOffset(TextLocation)"/>
        TextLocation GetLocation(int offset);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset at which the text is inserted.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The new text.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Anchors positioned exactly at the insertion offset will move according to their movement type.
        /// For AnchorMovementType.Default, they will move behind the inserted text.
        /// The caret will also move behind the inserted text.
        /// </remarks>
        void Insert(int offset, string text);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset at which the text is inserted.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The new text.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Anchors positioned exactly at the insertion offset will move according to their movement type.
        /// For AnchorMovementType.Default, they will move behind the inserted text.
        /// The caret will also move behind the inserted text.
        /// </remarks>
        void Insert(int offset, ITextSource text);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset at which the text is inserted.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The new text.</param>
        /// <param name="defaultAnchorMovementType">
        /// Anchors positioned exactly at the insertion offset will move according to the anchor's movement type.
        /// For AnchorMovementType.Default, they will move according to the movement type specified by this parameter.
        /// The caret will also move according to the <paramref name="defaultAnchorMovementType"/> parameter.
        /// </param>
        void Insert(int offset, string text, AnchorMovementType defaultAnchorMovementType);

        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The offset at which the text is inserted.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The new text.</param>
        /// <param name="defaultAnchorMovementType">
        /// Anchors positioned exactly at the insertion offset will move according to the anchor's movement type.
        /// For AnchorMovementType.Default, they will move according to the movement type specified by this parameter.
        /// The caret will also move according to the <paramref name="defaultAnchorMovementType"/> parameter.
        /// </param>
        void Insert(int offset, ITextSource text, AnchorMovementType defaultAnchorMovementType);

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">Starting offset of the text to be removed.</param>
        /// <param name="length">Length of the text to be removed.</param>
        void Remove(int offset, int length);

        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The starting offset of the text to be replaced.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The length of the text to be replaced.</param>
        /// <param name="newText">The new text.</param>
        void Replace(int offset, int length, string newText);

        /// <summary>
        /// Replaces text.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offset">The starting offset of the text to be replaced.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The length of the text to be replaced.</param>
        /// <param name="newText">The new text.</param>
        void Replace(int offset, int length, ITextSource newText);

        /// <summary>
        /// Make the document combine the following actions into a single
        /// action for undo purposes.
        /// </summary>
        void StartUndoableAction();

        /// <summary>
        /// Ends the undoable action started with <see cref="StartUndoableAction"/>.
        /// </summary>
        void EndUndoableAction();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an undo group. Dispose the returned value to close the undo group.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An object that closes the undo group when Dispose() is called.</returns>
        IDisposable OpenUndoGroup();

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="ITextAnchor"/> at the specified offset.
        /// </summary>
        /// <inheritdoc cref="ITextAnchor" select="remarks|example"/>
        ITextAnchor CreateAnchor(int offset);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the file the document is stored in.
        /// Could also be a non-existent dummy file name or null if no name has been set.
        /// </summary>
        string FileName { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when the file name of the document changes.
        /// </summary>
        event EventHandler FileNameChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A line inside a <see cref="IDocument"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IDocumentLine : ISegment
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the length of this line, including the line delimiter.
        /// </summary>
        int TotalLength { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the length of the line terminator.
        /// Returns 1 or 2; or 0 at the end of the document.
        /// </summary>
        int DelimiterLength { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of this line.
        /// The first line has the number 1.
        /// </summary>
        int LineNumber { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the previous line. Returns null if this is the first line in the document.
        /// </summary>
        IDocumentLine PreviousLine { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the next line. Returns null if this is the last line in the document.
        /// </summary>
        IDocumentLine NextLine { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets whether the line was deleted.
        /// </summary>
        bool IsDeleted { get; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Describes a change of the document text.
    /// This class is thread-safe.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class TextChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        readonly int offset;
        readonly ITextSource removedText;
        readonly ITextSource insertedText;

        /// <summary>
        /// The offset at which the change occurs.
        /// </summary>
        public int Offset {
            get { return offset; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The text that was removed.
        /// </summary>
        public ITextSource RemovedText {
            get { return removedText; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of characters removed.
        /// </summary>
        public int RemovalLength {
            get { return removedText.TextLength; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The text that was inserted.
        /// </summary>
        public ITextSource InsertedText {
            get { return insertedText; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of characters inserted.
        /// </summary>
        public int InsertionLength {
            get { return insertedText.TextLength; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new TextChangeEventArgs object.
        /// </summary>
        public TextChangeEventArgs(int offset, string removedText, string insertedText)
        {
            if (offset < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset", offset, "offset must not be negative");
            this.offset = offset;
            this.removedText = removedText != null ? new StringTextSource(removedText) : StringTextSource.Empty;
            this.insertedText = insertedText != null ? new StringTextSource(insertedText) : StringTextSource.Empty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new TextChangeEventArgs object.
        /// </summary>
        public TextChangeEventArgs(int offset, ITextSource removedText, ITextSource insertedText)
        {
            if (offset < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset", offset, "offset must not be negative");
            this.offset = offset;
            this.removedText = removedText ?? StringTextSource.Empty;
            this.insertedText = insertedText ?? StringTextSource.Empty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the new offset where the specified offset moves after this document change.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int GetNewOffset(int offset, AnchorMovementType movementType = AnchorMovementType.Default)
        {
            if (offset >= this.Offset && offset <= this.Offset + this.RemovalLength) {
                if (movementType == AnchorMovementType.BeforeInsertion)
                    return this.Offset;
                else
                    return this.Offset + this.InsertionLength;
            } else if (offset > this.Offset) {
                return offset + this.InsertionLength - this.RemovalLength;
            } else {
                return offset;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates TextChangeEventArgs for the reverse change.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual TextChangeEventArgs Invert()
        {
            return new TextChangeEventArgs(offset, insertedText, removedText);
        }
    }
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какого типа ваш `textEditor`? У [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) я не нашёл метода `Load`.

У меня работает такой код:

```
var source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(@"D:\test.png")); // <-- подставляете сюда путь
var image = new Image() { Source = source };              //     к картинке
var container = new InlineUIContainer(image, textEditor.Document.ContentStart);
```

Comment: TextEditor переопределён `TextEditor : RichTextBox /*Control*/`

Comment: `var container = new InlineUIContainer(image, textEditor.Document.ContentStart);`


>Ошибка CS1061 'TextDocument" не содержит определения для "ContentStart" и не удалось найти метод расширения "ContentStart", принимающий тип "TextDocument" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Comment: @codename0082016: Хм. А какого типа ваш `textEditor.Document`? [У `RichTextBox` это `FlowDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document(v=vs.110).aspx). Откуда взялся `TextDocument` и что это такое?

Comment: Добавлен FlowDocument. 
 public sealed class TextDocument : FlowDocument, IDocument, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Добавлен FlowDocument `public sealed class TextDocument : FlowDocument, IDocument, INotifyPropertyChanged`
Ошибка `textEditor.Document.ContentStart)` исчезла .
Картинка не появилась в textEditor. Что дальше делать?

Comment: @codename0082016: Ну, хм. Я не знаю, что делает ваш `TextDocument`. Попробуйте мой код со стандартным `RichTextBox`'ом, он должен по идее работать. Попробуйте ещё `((RichTextBox)textEditor).Document.ContentStart`.

Comment: @codename0082016: Вы, возможно, перелопатили `RichTextBox` в вашем классе настолько, что он теперь не вполне совместим со стандартным `RichTextBox`'ом.

Comment: Так работает. Попытаюсь совместить TextDocument  и RichTextBox.
`<FlowDocumentReader  Grid.Column="1">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <RichTextBox Name="Window_2" FontSize="14" Block.LineHeight="1" FontFamily="Times New Roman">
                    </RichTextBox>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentReader>`

Comment: @codename0082016: Подождите, вы что-то делаете не так. `FlowDocument` должен быть подэлементом `RichTextBox` (ну или подэлементом `FlowDocumentReader`), а у вас наоборот почему-то.

Comment: Исправлено. `<RichTextBox x:Name="Window_2" >
        <FlowDocument>
         <Paragraph/>
        </FlowDocument>
       </RichTextBox>`

Comment: @codename0082016: В таком виде мой пример должен работать вроде бы.