# Где найти исходники RichTextBox и FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf

Ищу исходники RichTextBox и FlowDocument.

У меня TextEditor унаследованный от RichTextBox

Свойства перекрываются этой строкой:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextEditor),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextEditor)));
```

.

```
public class TextEditor : RichTextBox

static TextEditor()
    {

DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextEditor),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextEditor)));
```

Если её закоммнтировать то контроллер работает как RichTextBox.

Но не рааботают свойства TextEditor.

Без закомметирования - контроллер работает как TextEditor. Но в него нельзя вставлять картинки.

Частично пример моего кода здесь: [Как вставить картинку в RichTextBox?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-richtextbox)

```
public class TextEditor : RichTextBox

public sealed class TextDocument : FlowDocument
```

Comment: [RichTextBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs,dc23aa35ce336078), [FlowDocument](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/FlowDocument.cs,7049d8a35db73d0e)

Comment: @Grundy: А почему не ответ?

Comment: @VladD, потому что это ответы ссылки :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Набираем [sourceof.net](http://sourceof.net) и ищем:

- [RichTextBox](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/RichTextBox.cs)
- [FlowDocument](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/FlowDocument.cs)

Исходники тем со стилями можно найти локально в файлах Visual Studio. Например, у 2015-ой Студии они хранятся здесь:

> %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf

А строчкой

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TextEditor), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TextEditor)));
```

вы перекрываете не свойства, а стиль контрола по-умолчанию: теперь он будет равен стилю, у которого `TargetType` выставлен в `TextEditor`.

Стили кастомных контролов обычно задаются в файле `Generic.xaml` и выглядят следующим образом:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextEditor}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextEditor}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Важно понимать, что таким стилем переопределяется не только `Template` (по сути — разметка контрола), а и вообще все свойства базового стиля, т.к. `BasedOn` по-умолчанию равен `null`.

Если в новом стиле нужно унаследовать некий существующий стиль (в вашем случае это стиль `RichTextBox`), и тем самым сохранить поведение и разметку `RichTextBox`, то укажите `BasedOn` явно, и не затирайте свойство `Template`:

```
...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextEditor}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type RichTextBox}}">
</Style>
...
```

Comment: Ого, не знал насчёт DesignTools\SystemThemes\Wpf, спасибо!